# Why might questions show up in the wrong tag area?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

Why does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791328/what-are-the-differences-between-and) appear here in the [java](/questions/tagged/java) questions list (see screenshot) when it is not tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java) itself?

[image]

Comment: You can't post an image. OK. But why can't you post a link???

Comment: I did post a link... did you downvote for that?

Comment: You posted a link to the picture. A link to the *question* would have also been helpful.

Comment: oh... sorry. I tried to post a picture and when it didn't let me I changed it to a link. that would have been a better Idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791328/what-are-the-differences-between-and) was originally tagged with Java when it was created, less than 20 minutes ago. It has had Java removed, added, and removed again in its short life. Retags do not necessarily reflect immediately, they can lag for a very brief period of time.